# Why do objects stutter while I move and the camera is rotating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, rigid-bodies

I have began developing an fps script and followed a tutorial to help with the script. Everything works great now but the only issue is any objects in the view seem to stutter whenever the player is moving and rotating at the same time.
The script for the player's movement and camera rotation is below.
Can anybody point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

{

```
public Transform cam;
public Rigidbody rb;

public float camRotationSpeed = 5f;
public float camMinimumY = -60f;
public float camMaximumY = 75f;
public float rotationSmoothSpeed = 10f;

public float walkSpeed = 9f;
public float runSpeed = 14f;
public float maxSpeed = 20f;
public float jumpPower = 30f;

public float extraGravity = 45;

float bodyRotationX;
float camRotationY;
Vector3 directionIntentX;
Vector3 directionIntentY;
float speed;

public bool grounded;

void Update()
{
    LookRotation();
    Movement();
    ExtraGravity();
    GroundCheck();
    if(grounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        Jump();
    }
}

void LookRotation()
{
    Cursor.visible = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

    bodyRotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * camRotationSpeed;
    camRotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * camRotationSpeed;

    camRotationY = Mathf.Clamp(camRotationY, camMinimumY, camMaximumY);

    Quaternion camTargetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-camRotationY, 0, 0);
    Quaternion bodyTargetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, bodyRotationX, 0);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, bodyTargetRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSmoothSpeed);
    cam.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(cam.localRotation, camTargetRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSmoothSpeed);
}

void Movement()
{
    directionIntentX = cam.right;
    directionIntentX.y = 0;
    directionIntentX.Normalize();

    directionIntentY = cam.forward;
    directionIntentY.y = 0;
    directionIntentY.Normalize();

    rb.velocity = directionIntentY * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed + directionIntentX * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed + Vector3.up * rb.velocity.y;
    rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxSpeed);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = runSpeed;
    }
    if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = walkSpeed;
    }

}

void ExtraGravity()
{
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * extraGravity);
}

void GroundCheck()
{
    RaycastHit groundHit;
    grounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out groundHit, 1.25f);
}

void Jump()
{
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

}

Comment: You can try to separate your camera logic and update it using LateUpdate. It's better for everything to already be "settled" for that frame before the camera does its calculations. Even better, player and camera should be separate components.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because the frame needs to update the camera rotation and the player position at the same time. i would suggest doing the rotation of the camera in fixed update. because this will run at the end of each frame.

like this:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
         LookRotation();
    }
```

another thing i would suggest is to move the player while the groundcheck is being ran, because if you do it seperately i can see a bug coming up when the player moves faster then the code can run or something. so a tip would be or to run it inside the movement method, or call the method while you are calling the movement method.

this:

```
    void Movement()
{
directionIntentX = cam.right;
directionIntentX.y = 0;
directionIntentX.Normalize();

directionIntentY = cam.forward;
directionIntentY.y = 0;
directionIntentY.Normalize();

rb.velocity = directionIntentY * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed + directionIntentX * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed + Vector3.up * rb.velocity.y;
rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxSpeed);

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    speed = runSpeed;
}
if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    speed = walkSpeed;
}
   GroundCheck();

}
```

or litteraly copy and paste the code within your movement method.

Comment: Thank you for contributing. This unfortunately didn't fix the issue :/ Objects still seem to stutter while the player both moves and rotates at the same time.

Comment: i have tried this on my computer, and i am having no problems. i do see some stutter once in a while with your code but if i use mine then it does not stutter. maybe try to reset the component/remove and readd.

Comment: I tried a different form of fps code and this code has no problems. Thank you for the help regardless!